# How to Convert XML to Array (5X6) then rotate -90 degrees?

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, xmlconvert

I have an XML file which I saved in notepad:

```
<Layouts>
<BinCode>11111</BinCode>
<BinCode>11111</BinCode>
<BinCode>11112</BinCode>
<BinCode>11121</BinCode>
<BinCode>11111</BinCode>
<BinCode>11211</BinCode>
</Layouts>
```

I want to Convert this XML file to array then rotate the array to -90 Degree.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the conversion back to XML and chosen data types are just **illustrative**.

I've just put an algorithm pointer for you to get you started.

Basically, what we do is we create a main array which the length of is the number of digits which is 5, each of those arrays will contain an array of 6 digits.

We're going to populate them from the back, so we'll reverse the strings from the bottom up.

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(@"
            <Layouts>
            <BinCode>11111</BinCode>
            <BinCode>11111</BinCode>
            <BinCode>11112</BinCode>
            <BinCode>11121</BinCode>
            <BinCode>11111</BinCode>
            <BinCode>11211</BinCode>
            </Layouts>
        ");


        var binCodes = xml.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;
        int digitsInMatrix = binCodes[0].InnerText.Length;
        int[][] ints = new int[digitsInMatrix][];

        for (int d = binCodes.Count - 1; d >= 0; d--)
        {
            for (int i = digitsInMatrix - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (ints[i] == null)
                    ints[i] = new int[binCodes.Count];

                char item = binCodes[d].InnerText[i];
                ints[i][d] = int.Parse(item.ToString());
            }
        }

        string updatedXML = string.Format("<Layouts>{0}</Layouts>", 
            string.Join("", 
                ints.Select(x => 
                    string.Format("<BinCode>{0}</BinCode>", string.Join("", x)))));
```

Comment: What i want is to convert from: 
11111
11111
11112
11121
11111
11211 

to

112111
111211
111112
111111
111111

Comment: That's cool... it isn't something you said in your question though. I'm not going to be posting answers to your problems so you can change the scope of the question each time. Update your question with all the details. Input/Output what you've tried and what you expect.